# Unable to use mail secure ports

Tags: osx, postfix, openssl, dovecot

In postfix and dovecot i am only able to connect to ports 25 (SMTP), 110 (POP3) and 143 (IMAP), others such as 465 (SMTPS), 587 (SMTP TLS), 993 (IMAPS) and 995 (POP3S) i am unable to connect with mail clients (used roundcubemail and mail app).

I have also test with telnet at localhost, and those ports was not open, except 587.

It seems obvious that i am having a problem with SSL and TLS but i cannot figure out how can i solve this with OpenSSL that came by default at Server App 3 (I am using also OSX 10.9.5).

main.cf: http://pastebin.com/aEtC0AJt

doveconf -n: http://pastebin.com/bB2nacy8

UPDATE1:

I discover that i had to use,

openssl s_client -connect :

to connect to IMAPS and POP3S ports, and with 587 i can connect but it shows this error after and closes:

CONNECTED(00000003)
21821:error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_X_HELLO:unknown protocol:/SourceCache/OpenSSL098/OpenSSL098-52.8.4/src/ssl/s23_clnt.c:618:

I can also connect to HTTPS port and use it without problem.

It is my first time using certificates and seems a bit confuse for someone who have never used this before.

Anyone?

Comment: Did you enable imaps on Dovecot Configuration?Check with netstat -ltap command.

Answer (score 1):

for `postfix` you have to enable `smtps` service in `master.cf`:

```
smtps     inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
```

and then restart postfix. That should open port 465.

In `dovecot` your pastebin listing shows `ssl = no` on line 163 - change it to `yes`. You will also need `ssl_cert=` and `ssl_key=` settings added to point to your certificate. Then restart `dovecot`. That should open ports 993 and 995.

There may be more problems after you've done with the above changes but lets tackle one issue at a time.